# 恐れ入ります meaning on this sentence

Tags: grammar, meaning, set-phrases

i think "恐れ入ります" means "sorry" , "excuse me", but it has another meaning "fear".which is correct in the bold sentence
A:双葉さんから(コール)で聞きましにいつの間にか帰っていたと
(don't know A or B speak ):**サボタージュとは恐れ入ります**

Comment: Does it really say 「聞きましに」?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

「恐{おそ}れ入{い}ります」 placed at the end of a sentence as in 「～～**とは**恐れ入ります」 usually means "***I am overwhelmed that*** ~~~~~."

This is the usage in the sentence in question as well -- "***I am rather overwhelmed that it was (mere) sabotage***."

(When 「恐れ入ります」 means "I am sorry", it is almost always placed at the beginning of the sentence as in 「恐れ入ります**が**、～～～～」 with a 「が」.)